# Where is `MapAssert.containsExactlyInAnyOrder`?

Tags: assertj

I want to write something like

```
assertThat(myMap).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(
  entry("a", "b"),
  entry("c", "d"),
  ...
)
```

but I can't find the right method. `containsExactly` requires that the order of the map iteration be the same as the entries, `contains` only checks subset. There is `containsExactlyInAnyOrderEntriesOf`, but then you have to package the `entry`s up in a `Map`.

Does this exist and I can't find it, or is this a gap that I coded myself into?

Comment: It turns out that `containsOnly` is what I wanted. When I read the name, I thought it meant that the map couldn't have any entries outside the list, but might not have all of them, sort of the opposite of `contains`. But it turns out this is `containsExactlyInAnyOrder` by another name.